# How to store user-agent in database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, user-agent, usage-statistics

I'm learning to implement some statistics for my API (Koa.js) which serves Next.js client and React Native app. How should I store `user-agent` data in database (PostgreSQL)?

Should I store it in just one column as `user-agent` in `users` table?

```
// users

id | name    | user_agent
---|---------|-----------
1  | someone | Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
```

I saw a post says should use separate columns for more details. I believe it should be something like this:

```
// user_agents

id | browser   | engine   | os           | device    | cpu 
---|-----------|----------|--------------|-----------|------
1  | Chrome/84 | Blink/84 | Linux/x86_64 | undefined | amd64
```

In my case, I'm using `ua-parser.js` and its output is:

```
@ua-parser> {
  ua: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36',
  browser: { name: 'Chrome', version: '84.0.4147.105', major: '84' },
  engine: { name: 'Blink', version: '84.0.4147.105' },
  os: { name: 'Linux', version: 'x86_64' },
  device: { vendor: undefined, model: undefined, type: undefined },
  cpu: { architecture: 'amd64' }
}
```

What if I use separate tables like `ua_browsers`, `ua_os`, `ua_devices` and etc with `user_id` references to `id` of `users` table.

```
// users

id | name
---|--------
1  | someone

// ua_browsers

id | user_id | name   | version       | major
---|---------|--------|---------------|------
1  | 1       | Chrome | 84.0.4147.105 | 84

// ua_engine

id | user_id | name  | version
---|---------|-------|--------------
1  | 1       | Blink | 84.0.4147.105

// ua_os

id | user_id | name  | version
---|---------|-------|--------
1  | 1       | Linux | x86_64
```

- Would it be unnecessarily complicated and redundant?
- What if user use 2 devices actively, web and mobile, should I store both `user-agent` data? Or, replace last data with the latest one every time?

How should I store `user-agent` data in database for proper data analytics?

### Stack

I am using TypeScript, Koa.js, PostgreSQL, Redis, Next.js, React Native, Nginx, Docker

P.S. I use Nginx reverse-proxy anyway.

### Edit

From the comments:

> Why would/should a UA be associated 1-1 with “a user”?

Because I was doing research and saw this: https://docs.magento.com/mbi/data-analyst/analysis/track-usr-dev-browser.html

> When should you record this data?
>
> Magento recommends you add a new field called “Platform” or
> “User-Agent” to your “Customers” and “Orders” database tables to store
> this information whenever a user is created or an order is placed. If
> you are using a SQL database, this field should be a VARCHAR(255).
> Note that the User-Agent string is allowed to be much longer than
> this, but in practice it rarely exceeds this length.

Comment: There are quite a few user agents with different variants. You will not always be getting each field you specified for user agent. i.e. bot scrapes, crawlers, game consoles, etc. If you expect to have multiple UA to a single user, @user2864740's recommendation would create that one to many relationship. Often times "keep it simple" is a perfectly valid and acceptable choice.

Comment: Why would/should a UA be associated 1-1 with “a user”? Counter: make a case for that business rule. I log in to several sites from multiple browsers/devices (and across various updates). Perhaps a “known_device” table (ie. user can be associated with _multiple_ remembered devices which might include UA as one piece of ‘evidence’). This table could _also_ contain a device unique cookie or other ‘evidence’. Using the separate table allows for 1:M flexibility, adds implicit intent in the name, and _separates business logic domains_.

Comment: yup break each part out if you want simple select sorting counts and all that good stuff, make one to many relationship for multiple devices etc. but if your only going to display it its overkill, you already have a lib to parse it just parse it on the way out and store in a single column

Comment: Now, if it is _just for analytics_ (as opposed to immediate “validation”), just record the entire request (basic W3C format) _and_ the UA in “request” table and run queries on it later. Alternatively, an “audit” table could call out authorization events (and record the UA in that case, although this feels more like “request” information). Using such logging tables - append only! - also allows analysis of information such as number of requests over time. _This over-time information is lost in an upsert table design_.

Comment: With the “request” table design, without too much coupling of responsibility, it’s possible to store the _hash_ of a specific auth cookie of the request (this is available up-front). This _hash_ can be associated with a “logon” table mapping the hash of the cookie to a specific user ID, which offers request analysis and correlation with specific users. So “user” -> “logon/audit” -> “request” (including UA for analysis).

Comment: (In the above design the UA - and other useful request information! - becomes implicit to any audited information: account creation, logon, purchase, etc.)

Comment: Thank you gents/ladies for enlighten me. :)